# How to fix wrongly created json data?

Tags: python, json, escaping, quotes

I have big amounts of json data (that were loaded from wikipedia) that was created in following form:

```
 {"a":""b" c"}
```

I try to parse it out by json library in python:

```
js = json.loads(data)
```

This code shows me an error:
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter
So as it is understood that I need to escape 3rd and 4th quotes or change them by single quotes.
How this operation can be done automatically (meaning that I want to escape that quotes by program)?
thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more. How did you get this data, what do you mean by "doing operation automatically", ... Write a (complete) piece of (Python) code in which you attempt to do what you are describing - even if it doesn't work, we will understand better what you are asking for.

Comment: Are you trying to change the incorrectly generated data to valid data, or are you trying to fix whatever creates the data to generate valid data in the first place? (The latter would be better, and probably easier, too...)

Answer (score 0):

If it looks exactly as you described something like this would be a possible way

```
loop all occurences of ""
    replace with "\".
    from current position search for next "
        replace it with \"
```

All in all I guess you need to write your own parser.
If the errors are more complicated it might be a good way to use extend the json parser for error correction.
In case an exception gets thrown the parser tries to detect and resolve it. If not possible throw the exception.